# TortoiseGit: Unable to Git clone private repository on VPS using SSH

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am trying to git clone a repository using TortoiseGit. I only have access of SSH to my git repository on VPS. I am getting the following error:

```
git.exe clone --progress -v "ssh://git@xx.xx.xx.xx/home/git/git-repo/myproject.git" "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject"

Cloning into 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject'...
/usr/bin/bash: git@xx.xx.xx.xx: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, I am able to git clone my private repository using Git Bash on windows. That is strange. Am I doing correct while using TortoiseGit for SSH?

Comment: Are you sure your SSH key has access to aforementioned repo? Did you configured SSH key properly?

Comment: @DipenShah I am able to git clone using SSH but not using TortoiseGit. SSH key is already added to Git Server.

Comment: I just cloned with tortoisegit through ssh and my output doesn't have `ssh://` , `git.exe clone --progress -v "git@github.com:user/repo.git" "path/to/some/folder"`

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not familiar with TortoiseGit, it looks like you should be using a syntax which is common amongst many application where copying is done over SSH. That is: `<username>@<server>:/path/to/thing/that/needs/copying`. (Note the colon near the middle.)

I propose change the command you are running to put a colon just before `/home`:

```
git.exe clone --progress -v "ssh://git@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/git/git-repo/myproject.git" "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject"
```

Comment: The problem is specifically about TortoiseGit. I have no problem with Git Bash. Note that I am on windows machine.

Comment: So you are saying TortoiseGit definitely violates the usual syntax for using Git with SSH? Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes. TortoiseGit should work the same way as Git Bash but it is not working that way. I am able to Puull/Push to the Git repo using Git Bash but NOT using TortoiseGit. What is it that I am missing? I have tried your syntax but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Ah, well, if the colon syntax isn't working either then I'm not sure. Sorry for the noise, I didn't have enough rep to just leave a comment on your initial post ;) It seemed better to take a stab at it rather than leave it unanswered :)

Answer (score 0):

> However, I am able to git clone my private repository using Git Bash on windows

Since you are on Windows, try for testing to use and uncompress the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) portable archive [`PortableGit-2.19.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.19.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.19.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want.

Then setup a simplified path in a CMD session.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
set GIT_HOME=C:\Path\to\Git
set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%GIT_HOME%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Check that the exact same command than the one used by TortoiseGit is still working:

```
git.exe clone --progress -v "ssh://git@xx.xx.xx.xx/home/git/git-repo/myproject.git" "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject"
```

Finally, still from that CMD, launch the `Tortoisegitproc.exe` GUI executable, and see if the clone can proceed from this session.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to clone using ssh key, you need to create and add ssh key to git repositories ssh public keys. Use ssh-keygen to generate your ssh key